# Question about PHP usort function

Tags: php, usort

i've got a PHP script where i rearange a multidimensional array with the use of the usort()-function.

this is a sample array (print_r-output) of array $arr

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bjudningen
            [grade] => 5
            [grade_type] => calculated
            [orgname] => LInvitation
            [id] => 13975
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Coeur fidèle
            [grade] => 3
            [grade_type] => calculated
            [orgname] => Coeur fidèle
            [id] => 8075
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dawsonpatrullen
            [grade] => 5
            [grade_type] => calculated
            [orgname] => The Dawson Patrol
            [id] => 13083
        )

)
```

And this is my PHP script

```
function sort_movies($arr,$val){
  function cmp($x, $y)
  {
    if ( $x[$val] == $y[$val] )
      return 0;
    else if ( $x[$val] < $y[$val] )
      return -1;
    else
      return 1;
  }
  usort($arr, 'cmp');
  return $arr;
}

$sorted = sort_movies($arr,"grade");
```

I want to be able to sort the array on different subkeys (i.e. name, grade,id), but it doesn't work the way i do it above. however if i change `$val` in the sort movies function to the value `"grade"` it does work, so for some reason it won't allow me to send in a vaiable as the sort parameter.

what is it i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

May be try this by send index of subkey i.e. grade instead of name of subkey .

Answer (score 0):

With 5.3 you can do it like this:

```
function create_sort($key)
{
    return function($x,$y) use($key)
    {
        return $x[$key] - $y[$key];
    };
}
$sorter = create_sort('name');
usort($arr, $sorter);
```

Comment: my server is only 5.2 unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $val is only available within the scope of the function sort_movies(), not in the scope of cmp(). You need to just declare it as global. This will pull it into scope so you can use it within the cmp() function.

```
function sort_movies($arr,$val){
    function cmp($x, $y)
    {
        global $val; // <---------------------------------
        if ( $x[$val] == $y[$val] )
            return 0;
        else if ( $x[$val] < $y[$val] )
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }
    usort($arr, 'cmp');
    return $arr;
}

$sorted = sort_movies($arr,"grade");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php